# Why width includes border when box-sizing is content-box?

Tags: html, css

I have this html file

```
<html lang="en" class=""><head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen Demo</title>

  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-aec34940fbc1a6e787974dcd360f2c6b63348d4b1f4e06c77743096d55480f33.ico">
  <link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-8f3771b1072e3c38bd662872f6b673a722f4b3ca2421637d5596661b4e2132cc.svg" color="#111">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://codepen.io/hardkoded/pen/VwjvWBm">
  
  
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <style class="INLINE_PEN_STYLESHEET_ID">
    body {
  font: 14px "Century Gothic", Futura, sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
}

ol, ul {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.board-row:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.status {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
}

.square:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.kbd-navigation .square:focus {
  background: #ddd;
}

.game {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.game-info {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

  </style>

  
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/editor/iframe/iframeConsoleRunner-7f4d47902dc785f30dedcac9c996b9f31d4dfcc33567cc48f0431bc918c2bf05.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/editor/iframe/iframeRefreshCSS-e03f509ba0a671350b4b363ff105b2eb009850f34a2b4deaadaa63ed5d970b37.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/editor/iframe/iframeRuntimeErrors-29f059e28a3c6d3878960591ef98b1e303c1fe1935197dae7797c017a3ca1e82.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="mouse-navigation">
  <div id="errors" style="
  background: #c00;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  margin: -20px -20px 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
"></div>
<div id="root"><div class="game"><div class="game-board"><div><div class="board-row"><button class="square"></button><button class="square"></button><button class="square"></button></div><div class="board-row"><button class="square"></button><button class="square"></button><button class="square"></button></div><div class="board-row"><button class="square"></button><button class="square"></button><button class="square"></button></div></div></div><div class="game-info"><div id="status">Next player: X</div><ol><li><button>Go to game start</button></li></ol></div></div></div>
<script>
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  document.body.classList.add('mouse-navigation');
  document.body.classList.remove('kbd-navigation');
});
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    document.body.classList.add('kbd-navigation');
    document.body.classList.remove('mouse-navigation');
  }
});
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A' && e.target.getAttribute('href') === '#') {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
window.onerror = function(message, source, line, col, error) {
  var text = error ? error.stack || error : message + ' (at ' + source + ':' + line + ':' + col + ')';
  errors.textContent += text + '\n';
  errors.style.display = '';
};
console.error = (function(old) {
  return function error() {
    errors.textContent += Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(' ') + '\n';
    errors.style.display = '';
    old.apply(this, arguments);
  }
})(console.error);
</script>

  
  
<script src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-157cd5b220a5c80d4ff8e0e70ac069bffd87a61252088146915e8726e5d9f147.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script id="INLINE_PEN_JS_ID">
    function Square(props) {
  return (
    React.createElement("button", { className: "square", onClick: props.onClick },
    props.value));


}

class Board extends React.Component {
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      React.createElement(Square, {
        value: this.props.squares[i],
        onClick: () => this.props.onClick(i) }));


  }

  render() {
    return (
      React.createElement("div", null,
      React.createElement("div", { className: "board-row" },
      this.renderSquare(0),
      this.renderSquare(1),
      this.renderSquare(2)),

      React.createElement("div", { className: "board-row" },
      this.renderSquare(3),
      this.renderSquare(4),
      this.renderSquare(5)),

      React.createElement("div", { className: "board-row" },
      this.renderSquare(6),
      this.renderSquare(7),
      this.renderSquare(8))));



  }}


class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      history: [
      {
        squares: Array(9).fill(null) }],


      stepNumber: 0,
      xIsNext: true };

  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O";
    this.setState({
      history: history.concat([
      {
        squares: squares }]),


      stepNumber: history.length,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext });

  }

  jumpTo(step) {
    this.setState({
      stepNumber: step,
      xIsNext: step % 2 === 0 });

  }

  render() {
    const history = this.state.history;
    const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
    const winner = calculateWinner(current.squares);

    const moves = history.map((step, move) => {
      const desc = move ?
      'Go to move #' + move :
      'Go to game start';
      return (
        React.createElement("li", { key: move },
        React.createElement("button", { onClick: () => this.jumpTo(move) }, desc)));


    });

    let status;
    if (winner) {
      status = "Winner: " + winner;
    } else {
      status = "Next player: " + (this.state.xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
    }

    return (
      React.createElement("div", { className: "game" },
      React.createElement("div", { className: "game-board" },
      React.createElement(Board, {
        squares: current.squares,
        onClick: i => this.handleClick(i) })),


      React.createElement("div", { className: "game-info" },
      React.createElement("div", { id: "status" }, status),
      React.createElement("ol", null, moves))));



  }}


// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Game, null), document.getElementById("root"));

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]];

  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(0)) break;
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }window.CP.exitedLoop(0);
  return null;
}
    //# sourceURL=pen.js
  </script>


</body></html>
```

It's a tic tac toe game from this codepen link https://codepen.io/sophiebits/pen/qNOZOP (I've modified it a little bit).

When I used the inspect utility of Chrome to select one square, and looked at the computed css box model, it says the content of the square is `32px`. But in the css portion of the html file, I clearly set the `width` of the square to be `34px`, shouldn't the computed css box model have `content width` of `34px`?

I know that the default value of `box-sizing` is `content-box`, so the `width` property should contain neither `border` nor `padding`. That's why I have this question.

[image]

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković `box-sizing: content-box;` is the default, so width should't contain `border`, shouldn't either contain `padding`. But in my example, it's not the expected behavior of `content-box`, the blue rectangle in the screenshot should be `34x34`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is opinion-based. Also there is no value in discussing why the specs of [box-sizing property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) are set they way they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons (and some other items) use a box-sizing property "border-box" instead of "content-box"; this explains the different behavior.

Documentation for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

You can change this in css using:

```
.square{
   box-sizing: content-box; /* border-box */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, you method works. But I wonder why I need to add this line to my css, isn't content-box already the default ?

Comment: read the reference. Not all element have a defaul value of `content-box`. By default a button has a padding and a border. As scuh it is by default also set to `border-box`

Comment: no, it's not for buttons. from the documentation:
"box-sizing: border-box is the default styling that browsers use for the <table>, <select>, and <button> elements, and for <input> elements whose type is radio, checkbox, reset, button, submit, color, or search."

Answer (score 0):

See this very simple JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ue5f164h/

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

```
.box {
  background: blue;
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

For me, the width is correct!

[image]

You should give a smaller reproducible example in your question so that it's easier for us to debug what's gone wrong.

But as the other answer points out, the problem is that some elements have a different default `box-sizing` value.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the way box-sizing works is that, it determines if element width should include border or not.

For example -> If you have a div with width of 300px
By using `box-sizing: border-box` like so

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Then the width of this div element will always be 300px -> 20px of border and 280px of content -> by adding padding or changing border size you are changing the size of the content

If you use `box-sizing: content-box` like so:

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;  

  border: 10px solid red;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

The width of the div element will now be 320px -> 300px of content + 20px of border width.

So if you want your element to always have width or height of lets say 50px you would use `box-sizing: border-box`